# Is this spam, or just a poor answer?

Tags: discussion, spam, not-an-answer

This answer came up in a late answer review: [Designing a textual user interface using ncurses.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796493/1442342)

It reads like an advert and provides no links to the actual tool-kit "advertised", which makes it feel like spam, but it also seems like a (misguided) attempt to answer the question.

I just left a comment via the review queue, but should answers like this be flagged as spam, not an answer, just down-voted, or something I haven't thought of?

Comment: \*sniff\* smells like spam

Comment: Yeah I agree, it looks like an advert... The user is new so we can give the benefit of the doubt. I'd wait for him/her to reply or fix the answer.

Comment: @Alenanno actually he's not really new, he's member of SO for several months however this is his first post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't see that, but look at his profile: he posted in March, in other words 7 months ago, which was exactly when he registered. So he was "new" when he posted.

Comment: @Ale oops.. and I didn't notice he posted so long ago thought it was new post (OP here said "late answer") anyway spammer usually post more than once so personally I think it's honest attempt to help. Got no clue about the topic discussed there so can't know how good or correct this help is though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted as "Not an answer". The user left that answer on March 20th, and hasn't been back since. If/When they come back and they wonder why their answer was deleted, I'll let them know.

Comment: What comments? The only comment there is new from the OP here.

Answer (score 3):

I would call that spam (or at least an advert), but... in this particular case it doesn't really matter.

That user just tells us about his accomplishments, but doesn't provide any links or any other information that is relevant to be question. Thus, it should be flagged as "not an answer".